# Moving drawable follow the finger

Tags: android, graphics

I have class that extends View.

```
private class Draw2D extends View{
             public Draw2D(Context context) {
        super(context);
              }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        x = event.getX();
        y = event.getY();
        switch(event.getAction()){
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:{

            break;
        }

        }
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        ShapeDrawable rectangle = 
        new ShapeDrawable(new RectShape());
        rectangle.getPaint().setColor(Color.GRAY);
        rectangle.getPaint().setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        rectangle.getPaint().setStrokeWidth(3);
        rectangle.setBounds(50, 30, 200, 150);
        rectangle.draw(canvas);
    }
}
```

I want to  moving my shape follow the finger on screen.
What I should write in `MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE` to do what I want?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These Youtube tutorials do just this;

Link: 
https://buckysroom.org/videos.php?cat=6

Just watch the tutorials [71](https://buckysroom.org/videos.php?cat=6&video=16792), [72](https://buckysroom.org/videos.php?cat=6&video=16793) and [73](https://buckysroom.org/videos.php?cat=6&video=16794) and it should work.

Answer (score 2):

You need to track the coordinates of your drawable so you can compare with the touch x, y coordinates.

So basically:

```
// can modify to adjust speed at which drawable moves
int movementSpeed = 2;  

if (drawableX < x)
  drawableX += movementSpeed;
else if (drawableX > x)
  drawableX -= movementSpeed;

if (drawableY < y)
  drawableY += movementSpeed;
else if (drawableY > y)
  drawableY -= movementSpeed;
```

Then need to redraw your drawable with the updated drawableX, drawableY coordinates.