# Drawing tool on google maps in android

Tags: android, google-maps, drawing

I am need of some requirement like, I need to draw a shape on google maps and when the touch is removed, then do some action with the plotted area. Drawing and performing action is secondary. But the question is how could I achieve this?

Is there any predefined drawing tool(something like Location button on google maps) to be used in google maps, or do I need to go with customization? Please suggest, or provide any links. Please don't say that this is not possible.

[image]

I have gone through all searches and with the last hope came here for solution.

Please help! Any help will be appreciated!!

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: You can take a screen shot of mapview dynamically and then set it on a canvas .On canvas you can perform marking of area,drawing lines etc.But this is a very lengthy way AFAIK google map api does not provide a way to do so .

Comment: Do you want to draw this shape on some region on the map?

Comment: @MaciejGorski, Please see the image I attached. Wherever the user touches the map, it should draw on the touched region of the map

Comment: I got it working by referring this link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9427681/moving-drawable-follow-the-finger

Comment: But if we are showing a map, how can we treat it like a canvas, as done in the referred link? Doesn't google API provide us with this functionality?

Comment: I think that Rachita has it right.  You must either get the map view to draw on a bitmap, and then use the bitmap as the background for your drawing view... or, possibly a better idea, put a second, transparent view, on top of the Map view, and do your drawing in it.

Answer (score 2):

> how could I achieve this?

As G. Blake Meike suggested, put a transparent `View` atop the map (e.g., using a `FrameLayout` for Z-axis ordering), and implement your drawing on that `View`. There are various "fingerpaint" samples around that you could use as the starting point for your drawing logic.

> Is there any predefined drawing tool(something like Location button on google maps)

I fail to see what the location button has to do with a drawing tool. Regardless, there is no freehand drawing tool that is part of either the Android SDK or the Play Services Framework.