# Google Maps Drawing Tools for Android

Tags: android, google-maps

I need to make an Android app where the users have an option to draw a polyline on Google Maps and when the touch is removed, then do some action with the plotted polyline. Drawing and performing action is secondary. But the question is how could I achieve this?

Is there any predefined drawing tool (something like http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.in/2011/11/make-your-map-interactive-with-shape.html for JavaScript) to be used in google maps, or do I need to go with customization? Please suggest, or provide any links.

And can we extract the points to compare them with the ideal answer which was to be traced?

Comment: I haven't seen any tool.  But to draw a line you create a new polylineopitons class, initialize the points(geocords), initialize the line type and then add the polylineoptions to the map.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But the question is how could I achieve this?

With code. ;)

> do I need to go with customization?

Yes. You would have to code all the functionality yourself. AFAIK there is no library that does that and of course Google Maps Android API v2 doesn't (and most probably won't) provide such functionality because it is too specific. I still think this would make a pretty useful library.

> And can we extract the points to compare them with the ideal answer which was to be traced?

Yes. That would be simple after you are done with everything else.

```
Polyline polyline = ...
List<LatLng> extractedPoints = polyline.getPoints();
```

Comment: Sorry, but I haven't used Maps before. So we can code such that whenever a user clicks on a position, a polyline is created? Could you please guide me to a tutorial doing this?

Comment: Or can you please include a mock-up for polylines being created when user clicks on 2-3 different positions on map. Highly appreciated! :)

Comment: @AnkitAggarwal We have created a simple app for you during my mdevcon tutorial: https://github.com/mg6maciej/gmpaint

Comment: @MaciejGórski: This was done for making users make a river on Map. After getting the points as you stated, how can we compare them with the actual coordinates? Shoukd I only compare the beginning, end and middle point of actual river and the polyline drawn?

Comment: @AnkitAggarwal Writing an algorithm to see the "difference" between two lists of coordinates can be quite hard. I'm not sure how can I help you here. One could easily write a very long blog post on this topic or maybe a short book. Try to search for solution on the net. I'm almost sure someone already had this same problem.

Comment: @MaciejGórski: Since I don't require great precision, I'm going to go with comparing the beginning, middle, and end of two lists of coordinates, and find the rms of the distances. On a trial basis I can understand the tolerance I can keep. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Simply use google maps api [Google map API v2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#getting_the_google_maps_android_api_v2) 
following link might help you with the code.
[code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9427681/moving-drawable-follow-the-finger)

Comment: But these talk about drawing a line in code. I want to give user the option to draw a line on the map as an answer to a question. If that is possible with the API, could you show me an example. I couldn't find it in the documentation.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Polyline here is the link from where you can get the code for drawing a poly line. you can simple get the latitude and longitude from the user tap on the map then you can use that information to draw poly line.

Comment: google map api is the easiest way to handle map things. you just need to add business logic to get the user input and need to call the draw polyline function of the map thats it.